# Laravel: Sort models by models with relationship along with models with no relationship?

Tags: laravel, postgresql, laravel-5

I have a query that gets related numbers using withCount and I have a scenario in which I need to sort my records based on the sum of related columns' 'amount' column.

My setup right now works on sorting the records that has relationship but no relation records always appears on the first part before my records with relations. How can I put the ones with related records first before the ones with no relations.

This is on laravel 5.5

```
    $models = $this->models->withCount([
      'rl1 as total_rl1' => function ($query) {
        $query->select(\DB::raw('sum(rl1.amount)'));
      },
      'rl1',
      'rl2',
    ]);

    foreach ($columnToSearch as $column) {
      $models = $models->where($column, 'ILIKE', '%' . $term . '%');
    }

    $models = $models
      ->orderBy($sortBy, $sortOrder)
      ->paginate($perPage);

    $models->appends([
      'per-page' => $perPage,
      'sort-by' => $sortBy,
      'sort-order' => $sortOrder,
      'term' => $term
    ]);
```

My results right now are

```
array[
   record1: no relation,
   record2: no relation,
   record3: [total_rl1 => 20],
   record4: [total_rl1 => 15],
   record5: [total_rl1 => 10],
]
```

I want it to be like this

```
array[
   record3: [total_rl1 => 20],
   record4: [total_rl1 => 15],
   record5: [total_rl1 => 10],
   record1: no relation,
   record2: no relation,
]
```

Comment: what is `$models->orderBy($sortBy, $sortOrder)` supposed to be?

Comment: sortBy in my scenario would be total_rl1 while sortOrder is desc